# "Cannot call methods on BIGINT" error

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have a T-SQL query that I've been beating on for a while, it seems simple, but I get an error in the query designer when I try to execute it:

```
SELECT     Date, CAST(Date AS bigint) AS DateNum, Title, Earnings
FROM         dbo.Analysis_001
```

Whenever I try to execute/modify this in the designer, I get "Cannot call methods in BIGINT" as a pop-up error. Out of frustration, I tried executing it using "CREATE VIEW" and it worked... Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a **bug**:

- either in Management Studio - ["Cannot call methods on bigint" error](https://web.archive.org/web/20110821014501/http://dotmad.net/blog/2007/02/cannot-call-methods-on-bigint-error/) (Wayback Machine link),
- or .Net SqlClient Data Provider - [Stupid problem with BigInt converting!!!](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/22053658/Stupid-problem-with-BigInt-converting.html).

Related question: [SQL Server Cannot Call Methods on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16180347/95)

Comment: Anyone know what the cause of this was? All the source links are down.

Comment: @NickG I updated the links. Is it still a problem in more current versions of SQL Server? Also, check http://stackoverflow.com/q/16180347/95 for a related problem.

Comment: In my case it turned out I had a dot instead of a comma between field names in a select statement, which can cause the same error message in SQL 2016.

Comment: Similarly to NickG I had an erroneous typo that gave this error rather than something more accurate. Mine was in a ROW_NUMBER() construct where autocorrect had substituted a column name "Description" for the sort order DESC in the following...
`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MyTable.MyColumn DESC)` I saw this (with Description where I've shown DESC here) and on stpuid auto-pilot I added a dot so I had `MyTable.MyColumn.Description`.

This gave the error relating to methods on bigint.

Just in case it helps anyone.

Comment: Genuine bug in my case: **CAST(... AS bigint)** gives error message, whereas **CAST(... AS int)** works fine!