# SQL Server Cannot Call Methods on Date

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've got a DATETIME column in a SQL Server 2008 table called ShiftDate. I want to convert this to a DATE column in a query:

```
SELECT     ID, ScheduleID, ShiftDate, CONVERT(DATE, ShiftDate) AS ProductionDate
FROM       dbo.ScheduleResults
```

I am editing this query in SSMS. If I run the query in a standard query window, I don't get any errors. If I run this in the View editor window, I get the error "Cannot Call Methods on Date".

I've tried the CAST method but it gets the same error.

```
SELECT     ID, ScheduleID, ShiftDate, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE) AS ProductionDate
FROM       dbo.ScheduleResults
```

The full error message is:

```
Executed SQL statement: SELECT ID, ScheduleID, ShiftDate, CAST(ShiftDate as DATE).ToString() AS ProductionDate FROM dbo.ScheduleResults
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: Cannot call methods on date.
```

I am inclined to think this is a bug in SSMS, but I would like to get some feedback from StackOverflow folks as to how to convert a datetime column to a date. I can easily convert it to a string column, but it is not ideal as Excel will not see it as a date.

Comment: Don't use visual designers like the view editor. They are craptastic and full of bugs. Write your CREATE VIEW code in a regular query window.

Answer (score 30):

You are correct, it is a bug in SSMS.  I'm using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 and when I try to create a View using the built-in designer, I get the same error message as you:

```
SQL Execution Error
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
Error Message: Cannot call methods on date.
```

As @Aaron Bertrand mentioned, to solve the issue, select 'New Query' and create the View in the Query window.  For your code, it would be:

```
CREATE VIEW myView AS
SELECT     ID, ScheduleID, ShiftDate, CAST(ShiftDate AS DATE) AS ProductionDate
FROM       dbo.ScheduleResults
```

Comment: Just save the view regardless of the error and it should succeed

Comment: 4 years later ... and this bug is still not fixed ... :( This is very annoying, because I am forever unable to quickly preview the results of existing views as I am making changes to them in the designer.

Comment: 6 years later and this bug is still not fixed

Comment: 8 years later and this bug is still not fixed...

Comment: 9 years same bug

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be a real bug as mentioned above by  https://stackoverflow.com/users/464923/will, inherited from MS Access old days with all it's inconveniences, You have just to ignore the error message and save your view then run it in a regular SSMS window, no error will be thrown .

Comment: Nice one bro! Saved me lots of time

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that (ShiftDate AS DATE) should have a datetime format.
If you try this:

*CAST(CONVERT(DATE, ShiftDate) as Varchar)*

Comment: I realise this is an old post, but ... WHY?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the error can be ignored. Just save the view and query it outside the Design/"View editor" window (in a new query window) and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and use that when you need to convert a DATETIME to DATE.

```
USE [MyDatabaseName]
GO

IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM sys.objects 
   WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[FN_DateFromDateTime]')
   and  type in (N'FN')
)
   DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DateFromDateTime]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Codestalker
-- Create date: Mar 17, 2017
-- Edited date: Mar 17, 2017
-- Description: Return Date from DateTime.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DateFromDateTime]
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
    @InputDateTime DateTime
)
RETURNS Date
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @ReturnDate Date
        Set @ReturnDate = CONVERT(DATE, @InputDateTime)  
        Return @ReturnDate
END   
GO
```

Then in your view call the function to convert your DATETIME.

```
SELECT DateTimeColumn, dbo.FN_DateFromDateTime(DateTimeColumn) AS ConvertedDateTime
FROM dbo.MyTable
```

You will not get the error message and it is reusable. (Tested in SQL Server 2012)

Answer (score 1):

This problem is still present in SSMS 18.4. I just sent it to Microsoft as an "idea", and since Microsoft's attention to every given bug report depends (only) on the social support of it, if you want it fixed, please go and vote for it at

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/41135050-ssms-returns-error-on-valid-query-in-view-designer

Comment: Link is not correct anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this works...

```
CAST(CAST(YourDate AS char(10)) AS Datetime)
```

(Yes I know it is not Date, but it is one step closer)

In the same query, it worked in the outside select, but not inside the union all...

Don't ask why :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Convert option instead.

```
SELECT     ID, ScheduleID, ShiftDate, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ShiftDate,101) AS ProductionDate
FROM       dbo.ScheduleResults
```

You can look at the various options of date formats [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This bug is still present in Management Studio 2016, seems for now the only solution is to cast to a varchar and live with it if you want to use the query designer.

Comment: No - you can actually save your code and test it by running the view from outside of the designer. (i.e. select the view in the object explorer and execute from there).

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you mistakenly put the column multiple times after tablename.

Suppose TableName is `Person` and column is `Age`

and you have written in query like:

```
Person.Age.Age = 30
```

Hope my experience will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too today. In my case I mistakenly put a full stop '.' after a field in my `SELECT` clause, instead of a coma ',' do delimit columns in my select.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with the name ShiftDate of the attribute in the underlying table. When renamed to something that does not contain the word Date as the last characters, the view works. Try renaming to ShiftDateDD for example.