# How to convert date to drop minutes and seconds SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to get a count of trans per employee by day. The table i am pulling from has the long date form with hours/min/secs and think that is the reason i am unable to count the transactions b/c they are being treated as individual records b/c of the long date time.

So in the Select query, i tried to convert the date, but get an error message: Cannot call methods on date.

here is my code

```
SELECT ITR_EmployeeID, 
CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate, 1) AS TransDate, 
COUNT(ITR_TransType) AS TC
FROM  dbo.ITR
WHERE (ITR_EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')) 
AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'PO Inspect') 
AND (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
GROUP BY ITR_EmployeeID, ITR_TransDate
```

What i am looking for is the Transtype to be counted by date and grouped by employeeID

thanks!!

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: SQL Server 2008, thanks!

Comment: can't you just do: `CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate)`?. And then you need to group by that expression instead of `ITR_TransDate`. Also beware of using `BETWEEN` with a range fo dates if you are filtering a `DATETIME` column

Comment: like this?{SELECT     ITR_EmployeeID, CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate, 1) AS TransDate, COUNT(ITR_TransType) AS TC
FROM         dbo.ITR
WHERE     (ITR_EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')) AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'PO Inspect') AND (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
GROUP BY ITR_EmployeeID, CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate, 1) AS TransDate}

Comment: @jballard81 that fixed the `GROUP BY`, but if `ITR_TransDate` is a `DATETIME`, then you don't need to do `CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate, 1)`, just `CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate)` is enough

Comment: @jballard81 - I think he meant - group by CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate)

Comment: just tried this:SELECT     ITR_EmployeeID, CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate) AS TransDate, COUNT(ITR_TransType) AS TC
FROM         dbo.ITR
WHERE     (ITR_EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')) AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'PO Inspect') AND (ITR_TransDate BETWEEN @FromDate AND @ToDate)
GROUP BY ITR_EmployeeID, CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate) and still got the cannot call methods on date error

Comment: Be very careful with sloppy use of BETWEEN. This query will include rows with times of midnight on @ToDate, but not rows from 1 AM, 5 AM, 9 PM, etc. Please read this: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx

Comment: Where are you running this query?

Comment: @jballard81 that error doesn't seem to be from SQL Server

Comment: @Lamak actually it is, msg 258. I think the crappy visual designers will do this because they re-write your code in crappy ways before sending it to SQL Server. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180347/sql-server-cannot-call-methods-on-date

Comment: @AaronBertrand Look at that, had no idea about that error

Comment: @Lamak you'd only have ever seen it if you decided to use the designers in Management Studio. Which have sucked since before Management Studio was called Management Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this in a query window, not in some view or query designer. Stop using those. Please.

```
SELECT 
  ITR_EmployeeID, 
  CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate) AS TransDate, 
  COUNT(ITR_TransType) AS TC 
FROM dbo.ITR 
WHERE (ITR_EmployeeID IN (N'sweda', N'bakja', N'gebwa')) 
AND (ITR_TransType LIKE N'PO Inspect') 
AND (ITR_TransDate >= @FromDate AND ITR_TransDate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @ToDate))
GROUP BY ITR_EmployeeID, CONVERT(DATE, ITR_TransDate);
```

Get this query working with the right results in SQL Server Management Studio (again, in a query window, not the buggy visual designers). *THEN* get it working in whatever application code you're trying to implement it in, and deal with those issues separately (or create a stored procedure and avoid any problems you're having incorporating T-SQL query text into some other app).

Comment: fantastic! thank you. I also really appreciate the blog link, i will be reading that for the next few hours it seems! Also, i can say i don't really enjoy using SSMS, can you recommend a different software? I had no idea that the query design window i was using could cause this issue!!!

Comment: @jballard81 thanks! If you liked that post, you might also like [this one](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx)