# Aggregate by name and average value per day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014

I have data of the following format in a table (I have only shown values for two hours, but in reality I have values for all 24 hours):

```
Name    Availability           Date             ItemID
--------------------------------------------------------
S1          75        2014-11-11 19:00:00.000   1124023
S1          80        2014-11-11 20:00:00.000   1124023
S2          60        2014-11-11 19:00:00.000   1124010
S2          50        2014-11-11 20:00:00.000   1124010
```

I would like to get the average availability for the entire day in the following format in a view:

```
Name    Availability       Date     ItemID
--------------------------------------------------------
S1         77.5         2014-11-11  1124023
S2          55          2014-11-11  1124010
```

It's okay if Date in the output shows up as 2014-11-11 0:00:00.000 as well.

I tried the following, but it doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT Name, AVG(Availability), CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Date AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS Expr1, ItemID
    FROM dbo.ServiceAvailability
    GROUP BY CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Date AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current query is very close, you are missing a few columns in your GROUP BY clause. I'd also suggest a shorter way to get the date without time.

```
SELECT 
  Name, 
  AVG(cast(Availability as decimal(10, 2))), 
  CAST([Date] as date) AS Expr1, 
  ItemID
FROM dbo.ServiceAvailability
GROUP BY Name, CAST([Date] as date), ItemID
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d461c/6). Since you are using SQL Server 2014, you can just cast your datetime column as a `date` - which drops the time portion.  I'd also suggest casting your `Availability` column to something other than an `int` so you get a decimal.

Since you are using an aggregate function any columns in the SELECT list that aren't being aggregated need to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause, so you need to include `Name` and `ItemID`.

Comment: When I try executing this, I get the error message "Cannot call methods on date"

Comment: @wemblem That's odd, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: Its because date is a keyword. Try `CAST([Date] as date)`

Comment: @Hatsjoem So with CAST([Date] as date) it works, but only when I execute it as a new query. I still get the error when I try to design the view.

Comment: @bluefeet I am using SQL Server 2014

Comment: @wemblem read this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180347/sql-server-cannot-call-methods-on-date#comment23129703_16180347  If you using the view designer that's the problem. Write the view without the designer.

Comment: That did the trick. Good to know for future reference. Thank you!

Comment: @wemblem the designer is not your friend.