# Convert this query into a View - Declare/Set not allowed

Tags: sql, set, declare

I'm trying to convert this into a view. It works perfect, I just need it to be a view.

```sql
Declare @maxship varchar(20)

Set @maxship = convert(date,(select max(ShipDate) from dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New))

SELECT OrderNumOB, @maxship as MaxShipDate, _ShipDate, DATEDIFF(Day, @maxship, _ShipDate)
from   dbo.View_Orderboard_Acctivate
where _ShipDate is not null;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of the logic and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Did you try to rewrite this query with join that is a natural way for SQL to work with datasets, not single variables? This will give you the query which can be used as a view definition

Answer (score 0):

You can not declare variables in a view; however, you can use a Common Table Expression (CTE) to achieve what you are seeking to do. The code below is an example of using CTEs to achieve your desired outcome.

```
WITH CTE 
AS
(
SELECT OrderNumOB
        , convert(date,(select max(ShipDate) from dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New)) as MaxShipDate
        , _ShipDate
from dbo.View_Orderboard_Acctivate
where _ShipDate is not null
)

SELECT OrderNumOB
        , MaxShipDate
        , _ShipDate
        , DATEDIFF(Day, MaxShipDate, _ShipDate)
FROM CTE
```

Another alternative would be to do it all inline like this...

```
SELECT OrderNumOB
        , convert(date,(select max(ShipDate) from dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New)) as MaxShipDate
        , _ShipDate
        , DATEDIFF(Day, convert(date,(select max(ShipDate) from dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New)), _ShipDate)
from dbo.View_Orderboard_Acctivate
where _ShipDate is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not smart enough to know why, but when I plugged this into SMS, it "corrected" things, and it broke.  I know its hard to write something without having all of the data to support the question, but do you see anything quick that might be a reason for this?

```html
WITH CTE AS (SELECT OrderNumOB, CONVERT(date,
                                        (SELECT MAX(ShipDate) AS Expr1
                                        FROM    dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New)) AS MaxShipDate, _ShipDate
                       FROM   dbo.View_Orderboard_Acctivate
                       WHERE (_ShipDate IS NOT NULL))
    SELECT OrderNumOB, MaxShipDate, _ShipDate, DATEDIFF(Day, MaxShipDate, _ShipDate) AS Expr1
   FROM    CTE AS CTE_1
```

I got this error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well... I'm glad I found this!  The problem is apparently a but in SMS for YEARS!  @ItalianStallion4215, your code is 100% correct. I had to put this in a query, and create view form the query.  This post explained the error I received.

[SQL Server Cannot Call Methods on Date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16180347/sql-server-cannot-call-methods-on-date)

Thus, this code worked, but I had to create the view not in the view editor, but in a query.

```html
Create View TestView as

WITH CTE AS (SELECT OrderNumOB, CONVERT(date,
                                        (SELECT MAX(ShipDate) AS Expr1
                                        FROM    dbo.Valve_One_Worksheet_New)) AS MaxShipDate, _ShipDate
                       FROM   dbo.View_Orderboard_Acctivate
                       WHERE (_ShipDate IS NOT NULL))
    SELECT OrderNumOB, MaxShipDate, _ShipDate, DATEDIFF(Day, MaxShipDate, _ShipDate) AS Expr1
   FROM    CTE AS CTE_1
```