# MSSQL Adding .ToString to datefields

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

i have some querys in my new SQL 2019 Database that connect to a table in a different database (MSSQL Server 2016) via linked servers.
But Everytime there is a date field in that query i get the error "The function or aggregat .ToString could not be found or the name is ambiguous".

I found that there is a hierarchy-ID-Function named "toString".
But i cant see why SQL should be using it when i dont call it to.

When i delete all Date fields from that query it executes without a problem.

`SELECT * FROM [LinkedServerName].Databasename.integris.Tablename`

EDIT:
I just noticed, that SQL somehow edits my text.
[image: MyTest] is what i wrote into the vieweditor.
[image] is what the error shows me.

EDIT2: i set up the same linked server on an old SQL 2005 Server. Everything works fine. I guess because the 2005 server has no ToString() function... but im not sure.

Comment: Are you accesing to tables or views?

Comment: Im only accesing tables.

Comment: Is that your whole query, or is there more that you have left off?

Comment: This is all. The Fields that are Dates cause the error.

Comment: Are the `hierarchyid` columns on any of the tables? Or in a trigger, view or user-defined function?

Comment: `ToString()` would indicate that for some reason it is treating the column as a CLR datatype. Someone with similar issue here https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1744323

Comment: If you wrote `berechnungsdat_von AS test1`, why isn't that in your query? What is the actual, full, unedited query, and the actual definition of `Tablename`? Although a bug is not out of the question (SQL Server 2019 switched the default driver for linked servers), it seems improbable it would affect all access to `DATE` columns. Even so, you might verify you have the latest version of 2019 (CU12, as of writing) and that the remote database isn't using a very old compatibility level (this should not normally be a problem, but still).

Comment: Note that setting up a connection to or from SQL Server 2005 could not possibly demonstrate the same problem -- because SQL Server 2005 has no `DATE` data type, this was only introduced with 2008.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Mostert i wrote `berechnungsdat_von AS test1` to make my problem clear and to show the difference. i can use `Select * FROM [...]` or `Select berechnungsdat_von AS test1 FROM [...]`. it was just for clarification. `berechnungsdat` is just a field in the table.

Comment: @MartinSmith I found that post too but sadly the solution mentioned in this thread is no for me.

Comment: @Charlieface No.

Comment: Are you using one of the built in designers to run your query? Do you see the same if you run it in a new query window? Maybe related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/16180347/73226

Comment: @MartinSmith What the heck. I ran it in a new query window and it worked. But still. I dont call the .ToString() or any function to this field. Why does it get applied to it?
If i run the same query, the same way, with the same fields just directly on the server, the table is stored on, i get no error.
So i guess i just have to live with the fact, that its a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I can construct a situation that would recreate the error, but I can't say for sure whether this is what is happening in your case. It's hard to demonstrate in a comment though, so I'll do as an answer.

Suppose we have a table `t`, with a computed column `f`, which references function `dbo.f`, which in turn references function `dbo.g`:

```
create function dbo.g() returns int as begin return 1 end;
go

create function dbo.f() returns int as begin return dbo.g(); end;
go

create table t(i int, f as dbo.f());
go

insert t(i) values (1);
select * from t;
go
```

So far so good. But now we drop function `dbo.g` and try to select from `t`:

```
drop function dbo.g;
select * from t;
```

This will result in the error: `Cannot find either column "dbo" or the user-defined function or aggregate "dbo.g", or the name is ambiguous.`

Look at the definition of the source table and check for computed columns, especially computed columns using nested constructs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
But i checked the fields in the table. They are no computed columns.

This is a part from the script to create the table:
CREATE TABLE [integris].[anla_bewegung](
        [berechnungsdat_bis] [date] NULL,
 [berechnungsdat_von] [date] NULL,
 [buchungsdatum] [date] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]

But as i said, this is just a part of the table. (Just the Date fields)

Comment: What tool are you using to create your queries? You mentioned a "view editor"?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio v18.8