# java - "Cannot call methods on bigint." error (using JPA)

Tags: java, t-sql, jpa, jpql, bigint

I have been using JPQL in my queries in java. And I encounter this problem.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002]  (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call methods on bigint.
Error Code: 258
```

This is my query in jpql :

```
TypedQuery<WholeResultRecord> query = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW project.WholeResultRecord(v,c,h) FROM Vehiclehistory AS h JOIN h.vehicleID AS v ON h.vehicleID = v.vehicleID JOIN h.clientID AS c ON h.clientID = c.clientID",WholeResultRecord.class);
WholeResultRecord result = query.getSingleResult();
result.go();
```

WholeResultRecord.java

```
package project;

public class WholeResultRecord {

    private Vehicles vehicle;
    private Clients client;
    private Vehiclehistory history;

    public WholeResultRecord(Vehicles vehicle, Clients client, Vehiclehistory history){
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
        this.client = client;
        this.history = history;
    }

    protected void go(){
        System.out.println(vehicle.toString());
        System.out.println(client.toString());
        System.out.println(history.toString());
    }

}
```

I think the query is ok. Because the error line is in

> WholeResultRecord result = query.getSingleResult();

I've read about the others problem regarding this error but none of those are related to mine. They said **T-SQL** must be used?

Please help me in this. Thank you.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] 

(Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot call methods on bigint.
Error Code: 258
Call: SELECT t0.VehicleID, t0.AutomaticTrans, t0.BodyType, t0.CRNo, t0.CatalyticConverter, t0.ChassisNo, t0.Classification, t0.Color, t0.EngineNo, t0.FuelType, t0.GrossWeight, t0.MVFileNo, t0.MVType, t0.Make, t0.NaturallyAspirated, t0.NetCapacity, t0.ORNo, t0.ORType, t0.PlateNo, t0.Series, t0.Turbo, t0.VehicleFirstReg, t0.YearModel, t2.ClientID, t2.Address, t2.City, t2.FirstName, t2.isCompany, t2.LastName, t2.MiddleName, t1.VehicleHistoryID, t1.AuthenticationNo, t1.BCTechPersonCode, t1.BCUserCode, t1.CECNumber, t1.CertIssued, t1.DENR_Result, t1.DateInserted, t1.DateTimeTested, t1.DateTimeUploaded, t1.DocStatus, t1.EmissionPurpose, t1.HDDSerial, t1.isUrban, t1.LocalCertDateIssued, t1.PETC_AmountPaid, t1.PETC_CompanyCode, t1.PETC_OrNumber, t1.PETC_PriorityNo, t1.PETC_Result, t1.PETC_UnitCode, t1.Remarks, t1.Reprint, t1.Retest, t1.Server_DateUploaded, t1.Server_UploadConfirmationCode, t1.StatusCode, t1.StatusDesc, t1.TEST_OilTemp, t1.Technician, t1.TESDA, t1.TEST_AVE, t1.TEST_CO, t1.TEST_CO2, t1.TEST_HC, t1.TEST_O2, t1.TRAN_ID, t1.VHGuidKey, t1.ClientID, t1.VehicleID FROM vehicles t0, clients t2, vehiclehistory t1 WHERE (((t0.VehicleID = t1.VehicleID) AND (t1.VehicleID = t0.VehicleID.t0.VehicleID)) AND ((t2.ClientID = t1.ClientID) AND (t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID.t2.ClientID)))
Query: ReportQuery(referenceClass=Vehiclehistory sql="SELECT t0.VehicleID, t0.AutomaticTrans, t0.BodyType, t0.CRNo, t0.CatalyticConverter, t0.ChassisNo, t0.Classification, t0.Color, t0.EngineNo, t0.FuelType, t0.GrossWeight, t0.MVFileNo, t0.MVType, t0.Make, t0.NaturallyAspirated, t0.NetCapacity, t0.ORNo, t0.ORType, t0.PlateNo, t0.Series, t0.Turbo, t0.VehicleFirstReg, t0.YearModel, t2.ClientID, t2.Address, t2.City, t2.FirstName, t2.isCompany, t2.LastName, t2.MiddleName, t1.VehicleHistoryID, t1.AuthenticationNo, t1.BCTechPersonCode, t1.BCUserCode, t1.CECNumber, t1.CertIssued, t1.DENR_Result, t1.DateInserted, t1.DateTimeTested, t1.DateTimeUploaded, t1.DocStatus, t1.EmissionPurpose, t1.HDDSerial, t1.isUrban, t1.LocalCertDateIssued, t1.PETC_AmountPaid, t1.PETC_CompanyCode, t1.PETC_OrNumber, t1.PETC_PriorityNo, t1.PETC_Result, t1.PETC_UnitCode, t1.Remarks, t1.Reprint, t1.Retest, t1.Server_DateUploaded, t1.Server_UploadConfirmationCode, t1.StatusCode, t1.StatusDesc, t1.TEST_OilTemp, t1.Technician, t1.TESDA, t1.TEST_AVE, t1.TEST_CO, t1.TEST_CO2, t1.TEST_HC, t1.TEST_O2, t1.TRAN_ID, t1.VHGuidKey, t1.ClientID, t1.VehicleID FROM vehicles t0, clients t2, vehiclehistory t1 WHERE (((t0.VehicleID = t1.VehicleID) AND (t1.VehicleID = t0.VehicleID.t0.VehicleID)) AND ((t2.ClientID = t1.ClientID) AND (t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID.t2.ClientID)))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:469)
```

etc...

my tables are Vehiclehistory, Clients, Vehicles.

[image]

Comment: why are your fields final?

Comment: Can you post a longer stacktrace and the definition of the three classes (Vehicles, Client, Vehiclehistory)?

Comment: Are you sure this is not a [BUG][1] ?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557932/cannot-call-methods-on-bigint-error

Comment: dont mind the final. I forgot to remove it but still it does not work.

Comment: the keys are both bigint in mssql, and long in java. Just don't know how it happens and how to fix it. thank you

Comment: Why is the SQL including "(t1.ClientID = t2.ClientID.t2.ClientID)" ? The last part is clearly wrong, so why your JPA provider created that is the real question

Comment: You wrote an SQL query instead of a JPQL query.

Comment: I think it is a valid JPQL query because it does not prompt any errors in that line. I use it as a reference to the other table. (Vehiclehistory.ClientID AS t2) (Vehiclehistory AS t1) Is it wrong? Please correct me. Im trying to get all the data in 3 tables together as one using Vehiclehistory as the primary table

Comment: Is it not a JPQL Query? How does it differ? I select it as a NEW instance of a result object where my Entities Vehicles, Clients and Vehiclehistory can be stored in. thank you for your response. I used it as a reference http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/select#Projection_of_Path_Expressions_

Comment: So what are the classes? VehicleHistory should have a field of type Vehicle to be able to join. Does it? And the field is called vehicleID ???? doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Does VehicleHistory must have an Vehicle type field? I thought it just need it's vehicleID. I don't know what to do. My classes are Vehiclehistory.java , Vehicles.java , Clients.java entities from my database. Need to fetch all the data from the vehiclehistory joined in with the the 2 tables vehicle and clients.

Comment: I just found out that there is a type Vehicle and Client in my Vehiclehistory entity. and its name is like this 'private Vehicles vehicleID;' and just need to fetch the Vehiclehistory object. I get it now. Because in vehiclehistory object there is the vehicle object within it. Am I right? Thank you guys :D